# Does LCM have distributive property of multiplication?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, gcd-and-lcm

Is statement

$$
lcm(ax, ay) = a *lcm(x,y)
$$

true? (assuming all variables are positive integers)

*I would say yes, but I can't find any confirmation or counter-example.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true.

$$\text{lcm}(ax,ay)=\frac{|a^2xy|}{\text{gcd}(ax,ay)}.$$

Since $a,x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and $\text{gcd}(ax,ay)=a\cdot\text{gcd}(x,y)$,

$$=\frac{a^{2}xy}{a\cdot\text{gcd}(x,y)}=a\cdot\frac{xy}{\text{gcd}(x,y)}=a\cdot\text{lcm}(x,y).$$

Therefore, for $a,x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$, $\text{lcm}(ax,ay)=a\cdot\text{lcm}(x,y)$.